# Какие инструменты выбрать для разработки собственной системы дистанционного обучения?

Tags: php, python, веб-программирование, reactjs, фреймворк

Планируем разработку собственной системы дистанционного обучения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие инструменты лучше всего для разработки выбрать(языки, фреймворки и тп)?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше выбрать те инструменты, с которыми в умеете лучше всего работать и можете обеспечить поддержку на всём жизненном цикле проекта. Если вы возмёте инструмент о котором почти ничего не знаете и не умеете с ним работать, то вы соберёте крайне много банальных и не очень граблей в процессе разработки, что может привести к крайне плачевным последствиям.